# If my Red Three is not melded or in a meld then is it minus points? Canasta

Tags: canasta

**By which I mean, say I have picked up and displayed a red three.**
My opponent has gone out, with them having 1 Natrual 5s Canasta and myself having 1 Natrual Ace Canasta, with three 6 cards left in my hand, **is my red three (100points) minus points along with the rest of my hand?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red Three's are automatically melded and put onto the table regardless of how many, this is the case if you are dealt one at the start or draw one latter. In your case each red three you have is worth 100 points and they double in value if you have all 4

[Rules](http://www.canasta.net/canasta_rules.php)

> When a new hand is dealt, the hands of both players are checked to see if they contain a Red Three. If there is one, that Three is then automatically melded, and an extra card is dealt to the hand out of which it came. This procedure is repeated until neither player has any Red Threes left in his hand.

The only exception is if you have played no other cards and only have red three's displayed

> If a player goes out and his opponent has melded nothing but Red Threes, the value of those Red Threes is deducted from his opponent's score.